# How can I remove an orphaned event receiver?

Tags: event-handlers, health-analyzer

This began when we noticed the health analyzer reporting the following:

> [MissingAssembly] Assembly [ProjectSubsiteMaker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8132574c3fbdd6f] is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ITS_Site], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this assembly. One or more assemblies are referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ITS_Site], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these assemblies.

After some digging we found that the reference is in the EventReceivers table of the database.  This event receiver was part of a custom solution that has been removed, and is associated with a list that no longer exists.

I have tried to find and remove this event receiver through powershell and through the sharepoint UI but it seems that without a list that it is attached to, the event receiver cannot be found.  I could just delete the entry from the EventReceiver table in the database but I'm not sure if that would mess up some other reference.

How can we safely remove this event receiver from our database to stop the health analyzer from complaining about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe "Event Handler Explorer" can remove them for you?

http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1547

The tool is originally for MOSS 2007, so I think you have to rebuild it with the 14 hive dlls to make it work with SharePoint 2010.

I wouldn't removed things directly from the database since it is unsupported.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the tool.  It looks really useful for attaching and detaching existing assemblies but it doesn't seem to have the functionality to find and clean up a missing assembly.

Comment: I ended up changing the HostId of the event receiver to an existing list and was then able to use Event Handler Explorer to (hopefully) cleanly remove the event receiver.  It is not showing up in health analyzer now at least.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Manager ( http://spm.codeplex.com/ ) will also allow you to remove event receivers.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a Delete method on the event receiver collection on the list. Use that to remove the event receiver and update the list.

Example code in PowerShell here
http://blogs.solidq.com/sharepoint/Post.aspx?ID=80&title=How%20to%20add%2Fdelete%20an%20event%20receiver%20to%20a%20single%20list%20with%20PowerShell%20in%20SharePoint%202010

Comment: powershell is good for administration

Comment: powershell is good. Period :)

Answer (score 0):

We can delete using code see this link:
http://www.anmolrehan-sharepointconsultant.com/2011/12/delete-orphaned-event-handler-using.html

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer] for general guidelines.